# Async/Await to an Object Not Assigning

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, properties

I have an async/await function that is not assigning to an object and I don't know why. I'm consoling out the results and it appears to be kosher, but when it hits the actual assignment to an object it doesn't assign. I'll explain below:

So here is the code:

This is just a helper function for asyncForEach:

```
  async function asyncForEach(array, callback) {
    for (let index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
      await callback(array[index], index, array);
    }
  }
```

Then I have the following:

```
const asyncFunc = async () => {
  await asyncForEach(tempPosts, async (tempPost) => {
    if (tempPost.fileName!=''){

      console.log('tempPosts[tempPosts.indexOf(tempPost)]: ',
      tempPosts[tempPosts.indexOf(tempPost)])

      console.log("await fsPromise.readFile(__dirname+'/../picFolder/sharp/'+tempPost.fileName)", 
      await fsPromise.readFile(__dirname+'/../picFolder/sharp                
      /'+tempPost.fileName))

      tempPosts[tempPosts.indexOf(tempPost)]['data'] = 
      await fsPromise.readFile(__dirname+'/../picFolder/sharp/'+tempPost.fileName)

      console.log('after assignment and value of tempPosts in asyncForEach: ', tempPosts)
    }
  })
}
```

So here are the results of the three javascript logs:

```
console.log('tempPosts[tempPosts.indexOf(tempPost)]: ',
tempPosts[tempPosts.indexOf(tempPost)])
```

Results in

```
tempPosts[tempPosts.indexOf(tempPost)]:  { flags: 0,
  fileName: '1552601360288&&travelmodal.png',
  comments: [],
  _id: 5c8ad110ef45f6e51a323a18,
  body: 'asdasdfasdf',
  created: 2019-03-14T22:09:20.427Z,
  __v: 0 }
```

Which appears to be correct.

And

```
console.log("await fsPromise.readFile(__dirname+'/../picFolder/sharp/'+tempPost.fileName)", 
await fsPromise.readFile(__dirname+'/../picFolder/sharp                
  /'+tempPost.fileName))
```

Gives...

```
await fsPromise.readFile(__dirname+'/../picFolder/sharp/'+tempPost.fileName)
<Buffer 89 50 4e 47 0d 0a 1a 0a 00 00 00 0d 49 48 44 52 00 00 00 c8 00 00 00 62 08 06 00 00 00 15 df 9c 16 00 00 00 09 70 48 59 73 00 00 16 25 00 00 16 25 01 ... >
```

Which is the really long data buffer string that I want. Cool.

**HOWEVER**

```
after assignment and value of tempPosts in asyncForEach:  [ { flags: 0,
    fileName: '1552601360288&&travelmodal.png',
    comments: [],
    _id: 5c8ad110ef45f6e51a323a18,
    body: 'asdasdfasdf',
    created: 2019-03-14T22:09:20.427Z,
    __v: 0 },
  { flags: 0,
    fileName: '1552601320137&&Screen Shot 2019-03-09 at 10.03.09 AM.png',
    comments: [],
    _id: 5c8ad0e8ef45f6e51a323a17,
    body: 'adf',
    created: 2019-03-14T22:08:40.336Z,
    __v: 0 } ]
```

What? My call is `Object['newKey'] = await fsPromise.readFile(yadayada)` where `await fsPromise.readFile(yadayada)` is shown to work in a console.log. Why can't I do this, this makes no sense.

Comment: What exactly is wrong in the `after assignment and value of tempPosts in asyncForEach:` output? I can't spot the issue.

Comment: It should be showing a field with a key called data with the data in it. As in the data buffer shown in the console.log.

Comment: FWIW, `tempPost.data = await ...` would be easier. What if you do `console.log(tempPost.data)` instead of `console.log(tempPosts)`? Also what are these objects? Do they maybe already have a special `data` property that cannot be overwritten?

Comment: Yes, I've tried to use `tempPost.data` instead with similar results. These objects are mongoose models, notably *without* data entries. I guess my next step will be to instantiate the mongoose models with empty data entries and see if the lack of an entry on initialization is preventing assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just made a small test and it seems that you should be able to see output if in your case you try to fetch the 'data' property to print:

```
console.log('after assignment and value of tempPost in asyncForEach: ',tempPosts[tempPosts.indexOf(tempPost)]['data'])
```

**However** trying to `console.log(tempPost)` will not display `data` unless you have defined that key in your TempPost's mongoose Schema

If you wanted to manipulate tempPost as plain javascript object you need to convert tempPost model document into a plain JavaScript object by calling `toObject`, eg. `tempPost = tempPost.toObject();` after this your `console.log('after assignment and value of tempPosts in asyncForEach: ', tempPosts)` will give expected result.

*So this has nothing really to do with async/await and assignment, imo*

Comment: The answer was, apparently, that you can't add a value to an object *even if* it is pulling from a Mongoose Schema. Non-intuitive as I had thought that was possible so long as you were reading the value, but apparently this is not the case.